# Why would a query on a Windows server not work

Tags: php, mysql, linux, windows

I'm having an odd problem - unfortunately I'm developing on a linux environment but hosting on a window environment. On the linux the query returns the correct data, on the windows I just receive NULL...

```
SELECT *, (SELECT image_name FROM images WHERE images.id = news.image_id ) as image FROM news
```

Comment: Do you connect to the right database? Are you sure you have the data in there? There is no reason why it should not work.

Comment: Seems basic but you have migrated both structure _and_ data from one to the other yes? I've done this before which is why I'm suggesting it.

Comment: Please add more information about the databases, version, environment...

Comment: Are you getting also any errors? Does the DB hold any data? Are the DB versions the same?

Comment: It might be useful to check whether you're using the same versions and what you use to make the queries (code or SQL tool), and whether you're sure you're using the same data. (In code, `SELECT *` is generally not recommended, btw: specify which columns you want instead.)

Comment: It's MYSQL Server 5.5 and with PHP - if I try the query in SQL work bench still returns NULL - theres definately data in both as I've queried both seperately and return the correct data.

Comment: try executing the query from mysqlWorkbench or similar and see if it work, and it's related to the database or the server itself

Comment: I had a similar problem a couple of years ago -- at least it rings a bell. It came down to a difference between how MySQL handled NULL and NOT NULL on the Windows machine.  I fixed it by making sure that column definitions always allowed NULL in cases where that might occur (e.g. in your `news.image_id`)

Comment: No luck - I have set the column to not null anyways - it's very odd and makes me hate windows even more than usual

Answer (score 0):

Try an INNER JOIN.  you sql is specific to some DB

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it wouldnt work as written but you may try writing it as follows.

```
SELECT  n.*, i.image_name image
FROM    images i,
        news n
WHERE   n.image_id = i.id
```

This should return the same result as intended by the original post I think.